# SQL Report Builder pull one node from an Xml Data Field

Tags: sql, xml, attributes

I have a SQL  table called: tblDataPermit

One column contains XML Data and is called: XmlDataField

In SQL Report Builder I am trying pull the data from the Text1Size50 node as shown in the sample xml data below. In this case it would be "Kirby Vacuum"

If I use:
SELECT
  tblDataPermit.XmlDataField
FROM
  tblDataPermit

It will produce all content in the XmlDataField as shown below. I only want it to show "Kirby Vacuum".

I have also tried this:

SELECT tblDataPermit.XmlDataField.value('(/Text1Size50/@Text1Size50)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Result from dbo.tblDataPermit 
WHERE ApplicationNumber = '00000002'
ORDER BY Result desc

I get a NULL value.

Here is a sample of the Xml data field:

```
--<XmlDataField xmlns="MgmsSchema/Business_Information_Detail_Entry" ApplicationNumber="00000865">
  <Text1Size50>Kirby Vacuum</Text1Size50>
  <Text2Size50>Lowes</Text2Size50>
  </XmlDataField>--
```

Comment: Please **do not poste pictures!**. Nobody wants to type in an example... And please state your tools (RDBMS: product and version, other tools). Especially XML approaches are very different on different systems. Just one hint. As there is a (default) namespace in your XML, you will have either to `declare` it, or to use a wildcard in your `XPath`.

Comment: Hi Bill, Please use the edit option of your question to add further details. I'd suggest to delete this comment, as I've just added this XML into your question. Now you should edit your question to add details and provide information about your tools, what you've tried so far and what result you expect.

Comment: Btw: The XML, as you've posted it in your comment has got a forbidden semi-colon after the namespace...